# Merging accounts

Tags: support, status-completed, user-accounts

I have long been away from these forums. If I recall correctly, I used to login from my Google account. Still, my Google account seems to be no more tied to my original MathOverflow account https://mathoverflow.net/users/828/andrea-ferretti

Is there a way to prove that I am actually Andrea Ferretti and regain access to my account?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I log in into my old mathoverflow account?](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/15/how-can-i-log-in-into-my-old-mathoverflow-account)

Comment: Welcome back! Plenty of others had the (presumably) same issue when MO upgraded to SE 2.0. The comment linking to the old question should be sufficient; but allow for a few days for the thing to be processed; it is not the case anymore that the site's moderators can do this so there is some overhead. However, in case of trouble you can still contact them for help.

Comment: Thank you, I have done the process - hopefully I will get back the original account