# Missing all activity and questions I asked on this site

Tags: support, user-accounts, deleted-questions

Apologies if this has been asked before, but I had a few questions on this site  (some of them from when the site run its own copy of the software and before it became part of StackExchange) and I can't find any of them. In fact, as of this moment, I don't see any activity (questions / answers) tied to my profile which is odd. Any idea of what may have happened and how I could potentially find those questions and answers, and link them back to my account?

I'm tagging this with deleted questions, but I'm not sure if that's indeed what happened, since I don't recall receiving notification about them, and to my memory at least, many of the questions had been voted up a few time and had accepted answers.

---

Update:

- They are [here](https://mathoverflow.net/users/12103/roseck), but somehow not linked to my account.

Comment: I'm not seeing a thing, deleted or not. Are you sure they're from this account?

Comment: Thanks @ToddTrimble Yes. I had asked them with the alias "roseck" (I went through a couple alias changes many years ago), but it should be under the same email account  (I have emails on my inbox for it). One thing I'm noticing is that I had it registered under amelio.vazquez@gmail.com (that's where the emails came to) instead of ameliovazquez@gmail.com (Google groups these types of alias variations under the same email account). I now login through Google OpenID, so maybe that's the reason ?

Comment: Is this it: https://mathoverflow.net/users/12103/roseck https://mathoverflow.net/users/12103/roseck?tab=questions ?

Comment: @MartinSleziak Yes! Exactly thanks.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Now I wonder, if I wanted to get that activity tied back to my account (notifications, reputation, ease of access, etc.) do we have a process established for something like this?

Comment: When the site was migrated to the Stack Exchange network, many users had asked to merge their "old" and "new" account. This thread was related to that: [How can I log in into my old mathoverflow account?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/15) However,, lot of things might have changed since then. Perhaps mods can you help with this further. You could also try to check this: https://mathoverflow.net/help/merging-accounts

Comment: Yes, we do in principle, but getting it done tends to be very slow (it has to be done by a Community Manager). You can request an account merge by hitting 'Contact' at the bottom of this page (in gray).

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR**: As **Todd Trimble** said in the comments to the OP, I was able to solve this problem by clicking on the "contact" link in gray at the bottom of the site

One thing to note here is that the "automatic profile" merge operation failed. When I triggered this operation I got one email for each profile to "confirm ownership", of the corresponding profile and after that, I got directed to a URL that said *`"The account X will be deleted and all rep and votes will be transferred to account Y as a result of this merge"`*, but I actually wanted the opposite (`Y` to be deleted and `X` to be the one remaining). I didn't see any option to choose otherwise, so I proceeded by clicking "OK" (thinking that it wouldn't make much of a difference other than the profile description / picture itself), but I actually didn't see any changes.

So I went back to the "contact" link, and this time I chose "Other", where I could send a custom message to a person with what's effectively the same text that I wrote in my paragraph above. In less than 8 hours (same day) I got a response confirming they had finished the operation, and I verified that it worked well, so I'm all set :) Thanks all and SE for your help!