# How do I recover my MathOverflow account?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I've been inactive for close to a year due to illness--and want to resume my activity as in

[Euclidean volume of the unit ball of matrices under the matrix norm](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1464/euclidean-volume-of-the-unit-ball-of-matrices-under-the-matrix-norm/3151#3151)

but when I try to do so, I get treated as a first-time user--https://mathoverflow.net/users/245703/paul-b-slater. (My university migrated my email slater@kitp.ucsb.edu to a gmail account--paulslater@ucsb.edu, and there seems to be some mess about login id's.)

Comment: Go to your current profile page; at the bottom left choose "Contact", then "I need to merge user profiles" in the "What can we help you with?" drop-down menu. In the body of the message place the current profile and the old one, and the SE team will merge the old into the new for you.

Comment: Thanks--will try!

Comment: Just for the record, I'll add that the way suggested by @AlexM. is mentioned also in the help center: https://mathoverflow.net/help/merging-accounts

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I log in into my old mathoverflow account?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/15/how-can-i-log-in-into-my-old-mathoverflow-account)